# Migrate EE install from enginehosting to acrustech and change domain name

Tags: server-migration, configuration-variables, domain

My legacy site EE2.3 and mysql database for an expired domain name has been migrated from Enginehosting.com to Acrustech. I have the new login information for accessing control panel, database, and sftp. I can login successfully to see the site via ftp, but haven't figured out how to connect to the control panel or mysql database. The new domain name is not yet live, the old domain name is inactive, the IP address is known and is unique. It appears I have to manually edit some of the installer information to get the system working. Given this information, if I update system/expressionengine/config and system/expressionengine/database with the correct server info, passwords, and ip address in lieu of the old domain name, should that allow me to connect to the database and control panel?

Comment: Is your database and web root been transferred over? I need that info before I can type up instructions.

Comment: My database and web root have been transferred over. Also I have updated system/expressionengine/config.php and database.php with new credentials and changed all the paths to the new domain name. Using the IP address I can now see the web site and also access the control panel login page, so things appear to be up and running. Only one problem - I can't login to the control panel. The old superuser login/password do not work. Is this something I can change in any other way? I've asked Tech support for assistance since they copied the files to the new server.